Nodejs Socket.io v4 disconnection problem on 1000 connections with 100 subscription each
I am trying to create one application using nodejs socket.io with version 4.
I am using very simple script that is accepting a connection and send a JSON dummy ({"abc":"abc"}) payload on an event(say 'loaddata' event) into a socket room which is created on event call(if it is not already created).
While benchmarking, if i try to make 1000 connections with 100 common subscription(100 rooms), then it starts giving disconnection error of few socket connections after few seconds.
Server(where socket code is running) Machine details : 8cpu,8Gb RAM.
After TOP command usage, it seems , CPU is over 100% when i shoot 1000 connections in a go with 100 subscription each.
is there some limitation in socket.io or i am doing some mistake or is this is the max limit for socket.io with this conn number. ?
//Server code : 


const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const {
    Server
} = require("socket.io");


const io = new Server(server, {
    path: '/abc',
    transports: ['websocket']
})

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    socket.emit('broadcast', `Welcome to StreamerIO `)
    socket.on('dataload', (data) => {
        socket.join('datafeed_' + data.token);
        sendFeed('datafeed_' + data.token);
    });
});

const sendFeed = (room) => {
    io.to(room).emit("getdata", {
        "abc": "abc"
    });
}

server.listen("7005", () => {
    console.log(`Socket Server listening on ${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`);
});


//Client Code :

const io = require("socket.io-client");

const connectFeed = async (subscription, tokens_list) => {

    const socket = io('ws://localhost:7005/', {
        path: "/abc",
        transports: ['websocket']
    });
    socket.on("connect", () => {

        function subscribetoken() {
            if (socket.connected) {
                if (tokens_list && tokens_list.length) {
                    tokens_list.forEach(token => {
                        socket.emit("dataload", {
                            token: token
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        function pingpong() {
            socket.emit("3");
        }
        setTimeout(subscribetoken, 1000)
        setInterval(pingpong, 1000)
    });

    socket.on('getdata', function(message) {
        console.log("received data");
    });

}

const startBenchMarking = (connections, subscription, tokens_list) => {

    var runConnections = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i <= connections; i++) {
            connectFeed(subscription, tokens_list)
        }
    }
    runConnections();

}
const NO_OF_CONNECTIONS = 1000;
const NO_OF_SUBSCRIPTIONS = 100;
const activetokens = ["a|1", "a|2", "a|3", ........] // an array of 100 diff tokens. 
startBenchMarking(NO_OF_CONNECTIONS, NO_OF_SUBSCRIPTIONS, activetokens);

i tried running above scripts with diff no of connections. it is running fine with upto 950 connections. and getting disconnections problem when connections crosses 1000+.
expecting : is there some limitation in socket.io or i am doing some mistake or is this is the max limit for socket.io with this conn number. ?

It's not the max limit but you're sending too much too soon.[

You're sending too much data, too soon, in the wrong manner. This is an unrealistic test.
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  // each iteration is measured in *microseconds* 
  // not milliseconds - microseconds! A millionth of a second
}

You have a synchronous for loop creating clients - which means that you're creating millions of connections in less than a second which is an absurdly unrealistic condition.
Node needs to run other tasks as well - i.e Garbage Collection to dispose of unneeded references and reclaim memory, and so on and so on. This means that for each connection you get a miniscule amount of extra latency.
In the context of millions of connections, these problems add up fast. The server starts getting slower on each connection attempt. You keep sending connections at the same rate and that miniscule amount quickly adds up.
Eventually the whole process becomes exponentially slower and you see a dramatic drop in it's performance until it rapidly exhausts it's available resources and just ...dies.
The solution is not to do this; it's an entirely unrealistic test.

Hi @nicholaswmin. Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually 1) this is our main requirement that when a client makes connections,it subscribes to multiple tokens in one go. And we are expecting atleast 1500-2000 such instant connections on starting of app.  So should i try some other socket library instead of socket.io? Because ultimately we need socket two way connections and this app is similar to like any trading app where connections comes instanlty in morning and subscribe alot of stocks in one go (example -loading entire watchlist)

@nicholaswmin Hi Rahul. A production deployment is going to require multiple, horizontally scalable servers.
Number 1 - Have you upped NodeJS max heap size? It's hardcoded at 1.5gb unless you explicitly increase it.
Number 2: - You're using only 1 core. NodeJS is single-threaded. You have to  spawn more NodeJS processes. This requires the Cluster adapter
Number 3: You must be able from the get-go, to also horizontally scale in a snap. For this you need one of the [Redis][https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/]
